# Is there a differense between a CONSTRUCT queries sent to a virtuoso endpoint and one sent to a Jena one?

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, virtuoso

I am trying to infer some new triples based on the following CONSTRUCT query:

```
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX dcterms:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX gpml:    <http://vocabularies.wikipathways.org/gpml#>
PREFIX wp:      <http://vocabularies.wikipathways.org/wp#>
PREFIX xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?line rdf:type wp:DirectedInteraction .
}
WHERE {
    ?pathway dc:identifier ?wpIdentifier .{
    SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
        ?datanode2 dc:identifier ?dn2Identifier .
        ?datanode2 rdf:type gpml:DataNode .
        ?datanode2 dcterms:isPartOf ?pathway .
        ?datanode2 gpml:graphid ?dn2GraphId .
        ?line gpml:graphref ?dn2GraphId .
        FILTER (?datanode2 != ?datanode1) 
        FILTER (!regex(str(?datanode2), "noIdentifier")) .
        { 
            SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {   
                ?datanode1 dc:identifier ?dn1Identifier .
                ?datanode1 gpml:graphid ?dn1GraphId .
                ?datanode1 rdf:type gpml:DataNode .
                ?datanode1 dcterms:isPartOf ?pathway .
                ?line gpml:graphref ?dn1GraphId .
                ?line rdf:type gpml:Interaction .
                ?line gpml:arrowTowards ?target .
                ?line gpml:arrowHead "Arrow"^^xsd:string .
                ?line gpml:graphid ?lineGraphId .
                ?line dcterms:isPartOf ?pathway .}}
                FILTER (!regex(str(?datanode1), "noIdentifier")) .
            }
        }
    }
```

When submitted to a virtuoso based SPARQL endpoint it returns the expected results. When however the same query is submitted against a Jena based endpoint, 0 triples are returned.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("/tmp/wpContent_v0.0.72733_20131216.ttl");
    BufferedReader constructQueryText = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sparqlQueries/DirectedInteraction.construct"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = constructQueryText.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');
        line = constructQueryText.readLine();
    }
    String queryText = sb.toString();
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryText);
    QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    Model results = queryExecution.execConstruct();
    basicCalls.saveRDF2File(results, "/tmp/directedInteractions.ttl", "TURTLE");
    System.out.println(results.size());
    System.out.println(model.size());
}
```

I have been debugging for over two days now, and I can't seem to find any error.

Is there a difference in how to write a CONSTRUCT query to a virtuoso-based endpoint and one that is sent to a Jena implementation?

Comment: I don't think there should be any difference in the result based on Virtuoso vs. Jena.  However, does either endpoint do any inferencing that the other doesn't?  Also, your Java code is doing a lot more than simply checking how much data is in the result set, which just means more places where something could go wrong.  How about simply `model.write( System.out )` or `System.out.println( model.size() )`?

Comment: Also, your query reading is overly complicated;  Jena's QueryFactory has a [`read(String url)`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QueryFactory.html#read(java.lang.String)) method that reads a query from a file.

Comment: Can you provide the endpoints that you're querying against so that we can try the queries?

Comment: It does not surprise me, though my problems are often more that the sub/superset of SPARQL that Jena and that Virtuoso supports differs. But, if not mistaken, Jena can come up with a custom strategy to fulfill a query, which could perhaps cause the end point to not return data in time, because Jena is trying to pull in too much?