# Virtuoso Jena Provider Construct Query Error

Tags: java, sparql, jena, virtuoso

My problem is similar to the one asked on this question:
[Is there a differense between a CONSTRUCT queries sent to a virtuoso endpoint and one sent to a Jena one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746689/is-there-a-differense-between-a-construct-queries-sent-to-a-virtuoso-endpoint-an)

I am using Virtuoso opensource as my graphstore and using the jena provider in order to access the data in that graphstore. I am doing several querys and everything is working fine (except for the amazing amount of memory and time that takes every inference with virtuoso but that should go in another question...).

The problem came when I tried to generate a model using a construct query. I have try using the `VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory` and the query as string and the default `QueryExecutionFactory` with the query factory:

```
qexec = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(queryString,inputModel);

model = qexec.execConstruct();
```

And

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,inputModel);

model = qexec.execConstruct();
```

The query gives the expected result in the sparql endpoint but an empty model when querying in the code.

```
LOGGER.info("The model is: {}", model);
LOGGER.info("The size is: {}", model.size());
```

Gives the following output:

```
The model is: <ModelCom   {} | >
The size is: 0
```

The model where I execute the querys is not empty and I did the same query from the sparql endpoint, as I said, recieving the spected results.

Anyone know where could be the mistake?

Thanks.

Daniel.

EDIT:
Here is the query I am trying to execute.

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX xsd:<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>  
PREFIX spatiaCore:<http://www.cedint.upm.es/residentialontology.owl#> 
PREFIX test:<http://test.url#> 
PREFIX spatiaCore: <http://www.cedint.upm.es/residentialontology.owl#> 
CONSTRUCT { 
    ?u ?p ?o1. 
    ?o1 ?p2 ?o2. 
    ?o2 ?p3 ?o3. 
    ?o3 ?p4 ?o4. 
    ?o4 ?p5 ?o5. 
    ?o6 ?p6 ?u. 
    ?o7 ?p7 ?o6
}  

WHERE { 
    ?u rdf:type spatiaCore:User. 
    ?u spatiaCore:id "0000000003B3B474"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>. 
    ?u ?p ?o1.
    OPTIONAL { 
        ?o1 ?p2 ?o2. 
        OPTIONAL {   
            ?o2 ?p3 ?o3.  
            OPTIONAL {
                ?o3 ?p4 ?o4.  
                OPTIONAL {
                    ?o4 ?p5 ?o5. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    OPTIONAL { 
        ?o6 ?p6 ?u. 
        OPTIONAL {
            ?o7 ?p7 ?o6
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see, the query tries to construct a graph with all the nodes the user is linked to with a depth of max five relationships and the nodes that are linked to the user with a depth of max two relationships.

Comment: You're not showing us the query or the data.  How can we know that an empty model isn't the correct result?

Comment: @AndyS inputModel is an instance of `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model` cointaining the data from the graphstore.
@JoshuaTaylor As I said in the question the data and the query are not relevant since `LOGGER.info("The model is: {}", inputModel);` shows all the data correctly and the same query executed on the sparql endpoint returns the expected model as results (that is not empty).
If is still too hard to understand the question I can try to make a minimun working example reproducing the same failiure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of method did you use for create VirtModel object?

NOTE:

If you used:

```
public static VirtModel openDefaultModel(DataSource ds);
public static VirtModel openDefaultModel(String url, String user, String password);
```

so the Model will contains only data from "virt:DEFAULT" graph.
And VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory will add next pragma to query text:

```
define input:default-graph-uri <virt:DEFAULT>
```

If you used something like:

```
public static VirtModel openDatabaseModel(String graphName, DataSource ds);
public static VirtModel openDatabaseModel(String graphName, String url, String user, String password)
```

so the Model will contains only data from  graphName  graph.
And VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory will add next pragma to query text:

```
define input:default-graph-uri <graphName>
```

If you want to use data from all graphs, you must call:

```
VirtModel vmodel = ....create model method...
vmodel.setReadFromAllGraphs(true);
```

If you set above to TRUE, the pragma for default-graph-uri will not added.

The worked example of using Construct with Virtuoso Jena provider:

```
url = "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111";
VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph ("test1", url, "dba", "dba");

set.clear();

String qry = "INSERT INTO GRAPH <test1> { <aa> <bb> 'cc' . <aa1> <bb> 'zz' }";
VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(qry, set);
vur.exec();                  

Model inputModel = new VirtModel(set);
System.out.println("InputModel :"+inputModel);
System.out.println("InputModel size :"+inputModel.size());
System.out.println();


qry = "CONSTRUCT { ?x <a> ?y } WHERE { ?x <bb> ?y }";
QueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (qry, inputModel);

Model model = vqe.execConstruct();
System.out.println("Model :"+model);
System.out.println("Model size :"+model.size());
```

Comment: Actually I don't use any of those methods. I used the next code in order to retrieve the data into a model.
`VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph(String graphName, String url_host, String user, String password)`
`Model inputModel = new VirtModel(VirtGraph graph)`
So I guess with this I just can read and write in the graph I am working with.

Comment: Why the UpdateFactory is created with the graph and the QueryExecutionFactory with the model?
Your working example looks exactly the same of what I was trying so I am still wondering where is the mistake in my code...

Comment: Now VirtuosoUpdateFactory works with VirtGraph only. (But it looks, that it must be updated for support Model and Dataset also). If you code is the same, so the problem may be with query. May be it returns empty resultSet.

Comment: As I said in the question, the same query executed in the SPARQL endpoint was returning the correct data.
I am going to accept this answer since it actually works, the problem must be something I am missing that differs from your code.
Thank you very much!